# SQL create virtual column depending on another table condition

Tags: sql, mariadb

i have 2 table, lets say `Main_Table` and `Favourite_Table`.

what i want is select all from `Main_Table` and create virtual column `_liked` at the end with value `yes` or `no`.

If Main_Table._category = Favourite_Table._category AND Main_Table._name = Favourite_Table._name AND Favourite_Table._email = 'someone_email' then Liked column value is `yes` else if not found or not matched with email then return `'no'`

at his time i am trying like this..

```
SELECT *, (case when 
    Main_Table._category=Favourite_Table._category AND 
    Main_Table._name=Favourite_Table._name AND 
    Favourite_Table._email='email@email.com' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as _liked 

    FROM Main_Table WHERE _category='Pop';
```

**MySQL said:**

**#1054 - Unknown column 'Favourite_Table._category' in 'field list'**

in `Main_Table` there is no `_email` column only on `Favourite_Table`

i think i need to add `JOIN` command but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try implementing this logic using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT mt.*,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Favourite_table ft
                      WHERE mt._category = ft._category AND
                            mt._name = ft._name AND
                            ft._email = 'email@email.com')
         THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS _liked
FROM Main_Table mt
WHERE
    mt._category = 'Pop';
```

The cause of your immediate error is that the `Favourite_table` doesn't actually appear in any `FROM` clause, so it is out of scope.  You might be able to fix it using a left join between the two tables, but I prefer exists here.

Comment: thanks for your fast response.. it work like i want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `left join` your `Favourite_Table` table.

```
select t1.*
    , (case when coalesce(t1._category, '') != '' and 
             t2._email='email@email.com' 
        then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as _liked 
from Main_Table t1 
left join Favourite_Table t2 on t1._category = t2._category and t1._name=t2._name
where t1._category='Pop';
```